# Two Elements Refuse to Float Next to the Third

Tags: html, css, css-float, figure

I've been trying to resolve what should be a simple float/ inline-block CSS issue for a few days now, to the point where I've personified the elements as jerks. The conundrum is as follows:

I've put 3 shortcodes all within a center-aligned `<p>` tag on my site. They are as follows:

- **A** = [shortcode_for_a_left_sidebar]
- **B** = [shortcode_for_a_figure]
- **C** = [shortcode_for_a_right_sidebar]

**A** is `float: left`, **B** (the main part of the three shortcodes) is set to:

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
```

and **C**, the poor guy, is `float: right`.

I want the three shortcodes to snuggle up as:

**ABC**, all on the same line.

**A**, being gregarious as usual, has no problem floating within **B**'s left margins. **C**, on the other hand, gets shoved down to the line below! It looks like:

```
AB
  C
```

**C** certainly *fits* within **B**'s right margin, but won't stand shoulder-to-shoulder. And I can't figure out any reason as to why the code is behaving this way. Because they are on the same line/ wrapped in the same tag, shouldn't **B**'s margin automatically adjust to let **C** in?

I've combed through a bunch of similar cases and the answers seem to always be to implement what I've already implemented.  How can I get these three to be friends?

///Here is the live link to the [pesky floating elements.](http://eeveelutions.com/umbreon)

Comment: Put the `float: right` before others

Comment: Hopefully this solves it for you.  Otherwise, I would recommend creating a fiddle to demonstrate this.  You should avoid including links to external sites to demo issue.

Comment: @brewal I tried doing this on another similar post and it created the exact same float issue but mirrored -- now, BC are floated next to one another and A is kicked to the line below. Do you have any guesses as to why?

Comment: Thanks @steveklein, I don't post to SO often and so I wasn't aware -- I'll look into creating a fiddle.

Comment: Sure Nate no worries and very entertaining and clear post btw :)

Comment: @NateSirrah Just make sure the order is ACB or CAB. Just by moving the HTML on your website make it work. Also, you'll have to make sure your container is wide enough (min-width) to keep the floating elements next to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make an element floating right "shoulder-to-shoulder", you have to put it before the content that is not floating in the HTML :

```
<div id="my-float-left"></div>
<div id="my-float-right"></div>
<div id="my-not-floating-content"></div>
```

In your case, you will have to put the `.otw-sidebar-2` div above the `<figure>`.

Comment: That did it! Adding _both_ of the shortcodes that are floating before the figure shortcode, that is -- do you know why the CSS behaves in this way? I wish I could vote up!

Comment: I'm not sure to have the answer of *why* it behaves like this. I guess this was a choose to make in the first place. It might be easier to float elements that are becoming after in the HTML than before. You can however accept the answer if it solved your issue ;)